# How can i integrate tradingview chart with pyqt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, integration, tradingview-api

i want to integrate https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/ with my application.

Primarily i just want to be able to display the chart and be able to click the buttons etc inside a pyqt app normally but i would probably then also want to know which rate i am clicking on for python to see. Perhaps even add a new function to the chart so that i can click on for example a 'BUY' button, drag a slider to the right price and then send that information to qt/python so that i can then process it in python, maybe send info from python too and run a javascript function...

What is the best way to go about this?

Edit: Iv'e tried integrating a webengineview in my app and pointing to the code, but unfortunately this crashes the whole system(i think the graphics card locks up). I think this might have something to do with my nouveu drivers(linux). Anyone know how to fix this?